# count number of lines, tokenizing

Tags: java, count, tokenize

I would like to count the number of lines in a file, splitting it into tokens. I cannot seem to get my code working, could someone please offer advice. Thanks in advance

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class kup
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        FileReader fileInput = new FileReader("C:\\save\\input.txt");
        BufferedReader readInput = new BufferedReader(fileInput);

        FileWriter fileOutput = new FileWriter("C:\\save\\output.txt");
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(fileOutput);

        Scanner scanLine = new Scanner(readInput);
        String textInput = scanLine.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer stringtokenizer = new StringTokenizer(textInput);

        int tokenCount = stringtokenizer.countTokens();
        int lineCount = 0;

        while(scanLine.hasNextLine())
        {
            while(stringtokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                String string = stringtokenizer.nextToken();
                outFile.println(string);
            }
                lineCount++;
        }

        outFile.println("Number of words: " +tokenCount);
        outFile.println("Number of lines: " +lineCount);

        readInput.close();
        outFile.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: What about this doesn't work?

Comment: it doesnt print out the result on the output file, i think its lagging or some kind,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only initializing the tokenizer with the very first line. I suspect you want something like:

```
int tokenCount = 0;
int lineCount = 0;

while (scanLine.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = scanLine.nextLine();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);

    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        String string = tokenizer.nextToken();
        outFile.println(string);
        tokenCount++;
    }
}
```

Personally I would probably stick with `BufferedReader` for "reading line by line" - you're not really using any of the details of `Scanner` here. So:

```
String line;
while ((line = readInput.readLine()) != null)
{
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);

    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        String string = tokenizer.nextToken();
        outFile.println(string);
        tokenCount++;
    }
}
```

Note that you should be closing your readers/writers/streams finally blocks too, or using the try-with-resources statement if you're using Java 7.

Comment: thank you very much, it worked, but i dont quite understand what do you mean by you said that im just initializing my tokenizer with the first line. i'm sorry im just beginning to learn java. thanks in advance

Comment: @TokuchiToua: Look at where you're creating the string tokenizer - you're passing in the line. You're then *not* reinitializing the tokenizer in the loop, with each new line that you read. In fact, you never even call `nextLine()` - I'm surprised the original code terminated at all!

Comment: oh, i see. in fact youre right, i just forced terminate it. silly me. thanks again for the help.